# Existence of 2006 distinct natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Does there exists $2006$ distinct natural numbers such that the sum of any two divides the sum of all the given numbers?

Comment: Why $2006{}{}$?

Comment: It's from a 2006 contest I guess. But I was told that it works for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Perhaps this might help:  https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/NumbersDivideSums.shtml

Comment: Has to be a contest problem, indeed. Nevertheless, it is a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, and for any $n$, not just $n=2006$.

Suppose $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$ be a such numbers, with the desired property. Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Then observe that, $a_n+a_{n-1},a_n+a_{n-2},\cdots,a_n+a_1$ all divide $S$, and
$$
\frac{S}{a_n+a_1}>\frac{S}{a_n+a_2}>\cdots>\frac{S}{a_n+a_{n-1}} \geq 2.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{S}{a_n+a_1}\geq n+1 \implies a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\geq na_n+(n+1)a_1,
$$
which is a clear contradiction.